# Force iFrame links (in embedded Google Doc) to open in new window

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink, cross-domain, google-docs

Very oddly, there seems to be no way of setting Google Document links to open in a new window. (target="_blank").

When publishing a Google Doc and using the embed functionality, an iframe snippet is generated:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1mfSz_3cWh6eW-X3EhQTtCoZ33Km131An8Kyvmuxi5oM&amp;embedded=true"></iframe>
```

All links in the document will be opened within the iFrame and redirected via google's redirect service:
http://www.google.com/url?q=

Is there any way I can make these links open in a new window? I know there might be cross-frame scripting issues so it's strange Google has no simple way of achieving this ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, in lack of a better alternative I decided to Curl the Google Doc URL and do some jQuery magic before loading it in an iFrame.

Curl.php

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
[...]
$("#header").hide()
$("#footer").hide()
$('a[href^="http://"]').attr("target", "_blank");
```

Page.html

```
$("#google_content").html("<iframe width='100%' height='600' frameborder='0' src='http://www.example.com/Curl/Curl.php'></iframe>");
```

*Google, is this really the recommended workaround? ;)*

Comment: I know it has been a long time but was this the only way you got this working?

Comment: Unfortunately yes - but today there is hopefully a better solution!?

Comment: Here is a client-side JS solution I found: https://gist.github.com/psjinx/1f2317a50eb2b506ed84

Answer (score 6):

Here's my solution, avoiding `iframe srcdoc` since it's [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-srcdoc) in IE. The styles are optional.

```
<style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    iframe { margin-left: 2vw; margin-top: 2vh; height: 90vh; width: 90vw; }
</style>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe srcdoc="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $.get("https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1mfSz_3cWh6eW-X3EhQTtCoZ33Km131An8Kyvmuxi5oM&amp;embedded=true", function(html) {
            var contents = $("iframe").contents();

            contents.find("html").html(html);

            setTimeout(function() {
                contents.find('a[href^="http://"]').attr("target", "_blank");
                contents.find('a[href^="https://"]').attr("target", "_blank");
            }, 1000); // Actually not sure if timeout is required here...
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Any relevant drawbacks of doing this?

Comment: @FabricioPH Relevant drawbacks - SEO - not sure if Google correctly index such page. Example of mine - http://genesis.re/cruitment/ - you can view the source..

Comment: The gist link is 404, consider removing it.

Comment: First thought: you can edit the answer yourself, if that bothers you.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler, non-coding workaround is to embed the google document **from Google Drive**, instead of the 'published' google doc. 
Permissions can allow you to ensure document viewership and circulation is restricted.

Follow [this link](https://en.support.wordpress.com/google-docs/) and see the section under 'Google Drive'

This worked perfectly for us - links are opening without a warning that can frighten users.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue on our resources page here (https://ingeniumschools.org/icms/resources) while using the Google Doc Publishing functionality. End users would see the drive.google.com refused to connect image due to the links attempting to open in the iframe.
[image: Google Refuses to Connect in iframe embed]

The solution above related to CURL would not work for us since we needed to make this simple for the document editor.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295491/embed-google-docs-without-publishing) offered a bit of a hint I thought I'd try.

1. Publish the Google Doc as you would normally.
2. In the iframe embed code provided, swap the `src` attribute with a `URL` in this format: `https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/ENTER_YOUR_DOCS_ID/pub?preview`

This will embed your document with some annoying google headers and footers, but the links will open up in a new window instead of the iframe.