# Embed google docs without publishing

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

I would like to embed a google docs in a web page BUT I do not want to publish it. I do not want it to be searchable by search engines.

I want to share it with the "share > anyone with the link" option.
So I do not want to use https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=DOCS_ID&embedded=true but want to use https://docs.google.com/document/d/DOCS_ID/preview

I can embed it in firefox and chrome but IE gives me the following error: 
"This content cannot be displayed in a frame
To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame."

"publisher of this content" = "Google or me" 
clearly allows it for Chrome and Firefox. But why not IE?

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is ok now to embed. google resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set "X-Frame-Options" as explained in the good link below:

[Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)

Then you can simply uncheck "Require user login to view this form" in your Google form.

Go to File -> Embed and use the latest link in your website and it will work in IE also!
I was facing the same problem and I have solved it by this approach.