# iframe links of published Google Documents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, google-document-viewer

I have published a `Google Document` that contains some links. I have used the iframe code to embed it on a webpage. However, when clicking on its links, the iframe is being replaced by the link's target url.

I have tried to dynamically download the frame and replace a `div` placeholder (`ajax` + `jquery`), but it's not an elegant solution as there is basically an `html document` embedded on the parent `html document`. ( I have other problems with this approach)

I have also tried using the tag:

```
<base target="_blank">
```

but it doesn't work.

Another failed attempt was by using the `onload` attribute of the `iframe` element.
Then with jQuery I was trying to modify the `target` of all the `a` elements.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What sort of Google Doc is it? A document, spreadsheet? Can you paste the embed code you're using in a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate question. Workaround, An old one, On SO
[Force iFrame links (in embedded Google Doc) to open in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377324/force-iframe-links-in-embedded-google-doc-to-open-in-new-window)

Google docs requests for an answer [Here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/xQ1d3NAhxVE)

Comment: Oh god! I knew that I 've had to do something very stupid/weird to make this work..  Thanks!